# Grade 4 probability question - Cant answer it

Tags: probability, statistics

My boy who is in grade 4 got this question. Cant work it out.

Abby spins a spinner which has the numbers 1,3 and 5 on it. There is an equal chance of landing on each number.

Beth rolls a standard 6-sided die.

Abby adds the number on the spinner to the number on the die. Beth multiplies the number on the spinner with the number on the die.

Express, as a fraction in lowest terms, the probability that Abby's answer is less than Beth's answer.

For each number its not a straight ratio, for example outcome is 3 and 4. Abby would be 7 and Beth would be 12. What if we get 5 and 2, then Abby is 7 and Beth is 10.

Unsure how to tackle this one.

Comment: Draw a 6x3 table of all the possible outcomes. These 18 outcomes are all equally likely. Count the outcomes that satisfy the given condition and divide the count by 18.

Comment: EDIT* I think I get what you mean. Will try now

Answer (score 0):

| Spinner | Possible Dice roll |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $ |
| $3$ | $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $ |
| $5$ | $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $ |

Now, in first case always sum$>$product. $(\because1+1>1\times1,\ldots,1+6>1\times6)$

In second case, except $3+1>3\cdot 1$, always sum$<$product$(\because3+2<3\times2,\ldots,3+6<3\times6)$

In third case, except $5+1>5\cdot 1$, always sum$<$product $(\because5+2<5\times2,\ldots,5+6<5\times6)$

Abby's answer is less than Beth's answer in $5+5=10$ cases. out of $3\times6=18$ cases.

The probability of Abby's answer is less than Beth's answer

$=\frac{10}{18}=\frac{5}{9}$